# Why ASP.NET Identity returns 401 instead redirect to login page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

I am trying to add ASP NET Identity to existing mvc5-project with code-first.
I have studied new project, which generated VS, and I readed many articles on the ASP.NET Identity.
For the most part, I copied the code from the template to my project. I just replaced DBContext on IdentityDbContext and few changes changes. Tables were generated by EF Migration and filled by Seed method through UserManager and RoleManager, so, I think, some part of code works as expected.

But, when I added [Authorize] to Controller (not WebApi, just Controller), and tried to get a page from the controller then I faced a problem - server returns 401.0 error, although the options set to `LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")`.

Here is my code Startup.Auth.cs

```
namespace App
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(CwDb.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnValidateIdentity =
                        SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, User>(
                            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Startup.cs

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(CarWashApplication.Startup))]
namespace App
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

I need only simple auth with login/pass and cookies, I don't need auth by social network and etc.

Where am I wrong? How get redirection like in vs-generated template?

Comment: Is there a Login action in the Account controller?

Comment: Yes, but I tried rename LoginPath to nonexistent path in VS-generated project, and redirection to the path  worked, although it returns 404

Comment: that should be in Startup.Auth.cs in your App_Start folder, not the Startup.cs from the root of the project. I'm just guessing here, even doe it is the same Startup class(but different partials), the compiler and runtime might look at them in different ways... it's worth trying if you don't have them placed like this.

Comment: If they were from different classes, the project would not compile, because method ConfigureAuth(app) is not in class Startup.cs;
I added startup.cs listing in the topic

Comment: Do you have the [Authorize] attribute on the Login action? It shouldn't have one there, it should allow anonymous.

Comment: No, Login action and  controller are available without authorization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I just added `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` to the project and it worked. Unfortunately, no article that I have seen has any information about the necessity of this library.